# Difference between 100Mbps 1000Mbps INITIALIZATION-state

Tags: ethernet, tcp, duplex

What is the physical difference between 10Mpbs, 100Mbps and 1000Mbps (BASE-T) INITIALIZATION.

10Mbps and 100Mbps does not use all of the 8C8P(RJ45) pins. Does 1000Mbps utilize the full 8 pins for setting up the link, or does it use the same as 10/100Mbps?

**EDIT**

After some good input from reviewers I would like to clarify;
When I plug in the cable to the RJ45-connector. What will happen at the very beginning and are those actions standardized? Signals on specific pins etc.

Why I am asking if because I see strange behavior when I connect different end-devices to a switch. There is a HW-issue 100%. But it makes me wonder if my end devices uses different technique to setup the link.

E.g. One end device uses PIN 1 & 2 for first pulse. The other devices uses pin 3 and 4.

Comment: I think you are confusing some thing. layer 1 & 2 considerations like wiring, link speed, and duplex mode occur at a much lower level on the network stack than TCP does (Layer 4) so the "physical characteristics" of a TCP handshake are indistinguishable from any other activity when observed at layers 1 & 2.

Comment: Yes, good point! But if I use a CAT-cable with only 2 pairs it will make the handshake on those and establish a connection. Why I am asking is because I would like to know if there is a standard that says: "Always use the pin X & Y before using all other pins." Like a INITIALZE-state on the PHY.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia
[Ethernet over twisted pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair),
the answer is positive:

> **1000BASE-T uses all four pairs bi-directionally** using hybrid circuits and cancellers. Data is encoded using 4D-PAM5; four dimensions using pulse-amplitude modulation (PAM) with five voltages, −2 V, −1 V, 0 V, +1 V, and +2 V. While +2 V to −2 V may appear at the pins of the line driver, the voltage on the cable is nominally +1 V, +0.5 V, 0 V, −0.5 V and −1 V.[18]

Comment: So if I attach an oscilloscope I will see parallell communication on all pairs when the PHY has left RESET-state?
Setting up MDI-MDI or MDI-MDIX; are those specified on specific pins?

Comment: There is no concept of MDIX on 1000BASE-T; however there is a master/slave negotiation. This takes place on all pins simultaneously, so the answer is still the same.

Comment: @Aard: See IEEE 802.3 section 3, [p228](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVI34.png) and [p269](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDnsp.png). Although if I understand it correctly, MDI/MDI-X only matters during the auto-negotiation stage (which is the only part that's still done "the old way"), as afterwards the link switches to all four pairs bidirectional.

Comment: @u1686_grawity this is exactly what I was looking for.